# Proving a result related to Farey Sequence

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, farey-sequences

This is a problem from Tom M Apostol modular functions and Dirichlet series in number theory of Chapter -5 .

I am adding image of the problem
 [image]

I proved that fractions $\theta $  =$\frac{\lambda a + \mu c } { \lambda b + \mu d } $ always lie between a/ b and c/d. 
But how to prove that every fraction lying between a/b and c/d is of this form and $\lambda$ and $\mu $ are relatively prime.

Can someone please help with this problem.

Comment: About the Farey sequence, take a look at the references given in http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/farey.htm

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $c/d<a'/b'<a/b$ with $d,b',$ and $b$ all positive, and with $ad-bc=1$ and $\gcd(a',b')=1.$ Consider the simultaneous equations $$La+Mc=a',$$  $$Lb+Md=b' .$$  The unique solution for $(L,M)$ is $$L=\frac {a'd-b'c}{ad-bc}=a'd-b'c,\quad M=\frac {ab'-a'b}{ad-bc}=ab'-a'b.$$  We have $L>0\iff a'd>b'c \iff a'/b'>c/d.$

We have $M>0\iff ab'>a'b \iff a/b>a'/b'.$

If $0<m$ with $m|L$ and $m|M,$ then $m|(La+Mc)=a'$ and $m|(Lb+Md)=b'$, so $m=1.$

Comment: 1.how does this proves that every fraction lying between a/b and c/d is of this form? 2. and why can you choose both L and M >0 ?

Comment: I have no question in your answer except those 2 above.

Comment: CAn you please reply to my questions asked in comments?

Comment: Given $a/b>c/d$ and $ad-bc=1.$ For  any $a'/b'$ in lowest terms and strictly between $c/d$ and $a/b,$ we see that IF $L=a'd-b'c$ and IF$ M=ab'-a'b$ THEN $L>0$ and $M>0$ and $a'/b'=(La+Mc)/(Lb+Md).$